# Is there anyway to upload folder that contains sub folders using php

Tags: php

i want to upload folder with the sub folders but when i do it i never get the sub folders to upload, im using this simple code to upload

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Upload Folder using PHP </title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
  Type Folder Name:<input type="text" name="foldername" /><br/><br/>
  Select Folder to Upload: <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple directory="" webkitdirectory="" moxdirectory="" /><br/><br/> 
  <input type="Submit" value="Upload" name="upload" />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

```
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['upload']))
  {
    if($_POST['foldername'] != "")
    {
        $foldername=$_POST['foldername'];
        if(!is_dir($foldername)) mkdir($foldername);
        foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $i => $name)
        {
            if(strlen($_FILES['files']['name'][$i]) > 1)
            {  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i],$foldername."/".$name);
            }
        }
        echo "Folder is successfully uploaded";
    }
    else
        echo "Upload folder name is empty";
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: No you can't. This is a limitation of HTTP, not PHP. Only files can be uploaded, it has no concept of folders.

Comment: So its impossible to do it even with other languages ?

Comment: The language which receives and processes the HTTP request is irrelevant. The point is you can't send a folder over HTTP. Your problem occurs long before PHP gets involved.

Comment: Your options are: 1) Select all files in the folder and send each one individually. Then do the same for each subfolder. 2) Put all the files you want into a ZIP  file, and upload the Zip file. Then get PHP to unzip it at the server side. 3) Don't use HTTP for your file transfer.

Comment: that's a good idea, Thanks mate